# How to remove form field entrys

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that is filled with an database output. Before processing it the user can change the values when required.
How can I remove all entries with on click from column 'Aantal'

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td><img border="0" align="center" src="<?php echo $config['prod_image'].$image_fld[$i].'/'.$image_name[$i].$config['prod_image_type']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="aantal[]" size="2" value="<?php echo $aantal[$i]; ?>" <?php if($error_aantal[$i] == 'ja'){ $error_omschr = $error_omschr_aantal[$i]; include('includes/errors/input_error.php'); } ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="productnaam[]" size="35" value="<?php echo $productnaam[$i]; ?>" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="afmeting[]" size="15" value="<?php echo $afmeting[$i]; ?>" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="kwaliteit[]" size="15" value="<?php echo $kwaliteit[$i]; ?>" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="garantie[<?php echo $i ?>]" <?php if ("nee" == $garantie[$i]) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="nee">
        <input type="radio" name="garantie[<?php echo $i ?>]" <?php if("ja" == $garantie[$i]) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="ja">

        <?php if($error_garantie[$i] == 'ja'){ 
            $error_omschr = $error_omschr_garantie[$i]; include('includes/errors/input_error.php'); 
        } ?> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Proper code formatting

Comment: Do you want the `aantal` fields to be set to 0, or hidden?

Comment: I want it to be set to 0 @ZombieSpy

Comment: @Muiter if you look at my answer, do i understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"</script>
function reset_aantal()
{

        var i, totaal = 0;
        var elems = document.getElementsByName('aantal[]');
        var l = elems.length;
        for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
             document.getElementsByName('aantal[]')[i].value = '';
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly:

In your php file, that handles the form, make sure you're adding a `class attribute` to that column.
Also you should add a button or an element that clicking on it will trigger the hiding action.

For instance:

```
        <td><input type="text" class="aantal" name="aantal[]" size="2" value="<?php echo $aantal[$i]; ?>" <?php if($error_aantal[$i] == 'ja'){ $error_omschr = $error_omschr_aantal[$i]; include('includes/errors/input_error.php'); } ?></td>
```

Later on:

```
<button id="myHidingButton">Click to hide aantal inputs.</button>
```

Then, using JS you can write:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myHidingButton"); //The button.
button.addEventListener("click",function(e){ //The onClick event.
  //Get the element with the `aantal` class name and define the `i` variable.

  var colToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('aantal'), i;

  //Loop through all the aantal elements and hide them.
  for (var i = 0; i < colToHide.length; i ++) {
      colToHide[i].style.display = 'none';
  }


},false);
```

Comment: With the code above it starts processing the form instantly with the original numbers. The form should not be processed at when removing the entries.

Comment: I'm not following your agenda, what do you mean `it starts processing the form`. The hiding effect takes place only after the form has been already rendered.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `aantal` entries when pressing a button:

```js
// Using jQuery
$("#reset_btn").click(function() {
  $("input[name='aantal[]']").val("0");
});

// pure javascript
document.getElementById("reset_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='aantal[]']"), function(node) {
    node.value = "0";
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="aantal[]" size="2" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="aantal[]" size="2" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="aantal[]" size="2" value="3" />

<button id="reset_btn">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Just a notice: That's `jQuery` and this question was tagged with `javascript`. Moreover, you're just changing the `value` of the fields - not hiding them. `.hide()` would do the trick.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Oh ye, if pure javascript is what he want, your answer is better. But i was getting the impression that he want to clear data from the fields, not hide them. (i don't see the point of just hiding the fields)

Comment: Added pure javascript too

Comment: The values are not removed or set to 0.
When pressing the new button the form is processed.

Comment: @Muiter does my sample code not work, or does it not work in your code? Because in my sample code it sets the values to 0. And what do you mean by "processed"? You mean that you have a code that are processing the data when the values in the form are changing, but do not want it to?

Comment: Your code seems to work although not implemented in my code.
When I press the button the form is send to the database.